# EXCEL Substracting date Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 02:00 and hours (ex:4) gives error

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I need to calculate cutoffs to get the final time a truck departs from a node. Here below an example:

Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 02:00 - 4 ( Warehouse process Hours) = ERROR

I would like to manipulate everything in the query but if it is not possible I can work on a table. I have format the date above as date in excel. I have read that sometimes regional settings can give issues but I cannot figure out how to solve this. When I change the format in the query, I get an error. When I try to do the subtraction in Excel, I get an error.

[image]

Comment: Your date is coming in as text that looks like a date and not a true date. If you can control the format of the date in the export make it `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format.  Most regional setting will be able to interpret this as a true date.  But you need to do that on the import, after it hits Excel you will need to parse the string to make it a true date if you cannot change it at the source.

Comment: If you are unable to change the source and must deal with it in Excel, please mock up a tabular example of a handful of the dates and the other values necessary to show how you want the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply!

Comment: Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 02:00 4
Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 02:00 4
Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 02:30 6
Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 02:00 6
Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 03:00 4
Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 03:00 4
Thu 11 Feb 2021 - 02:00 4
So I take this data from a csv dumped in a folder. I would like to have in a cell the date with the hour substracted with the hour (4) so I can easily spot the right the last cut off

Comment: please [edit] the post with clarifications.  Comments cannot be formatted.

Comment: I have post an image that shows the query. Sorry for the confusing comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated the date/time is actually a string that looks like date time.  To do the subtraction we need to parse the date.  Simply remove the day and the `-` with:

```
SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,999),"- ","")
```

Then subtract the hour:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,999),"- ","")-TIME(B1,0,0)
```

Then format the output as desired.  I formatted it: `ddd dd mmm yyyy - hh:mm` to match the inputs.

[image]

Comment: Scott, thank you very much for the clear and very helpful explanation and for your time!

Comment: @Allrightallrightallright please consider marking the answer that you used as correct by clicking the check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score -1):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**:Edited:**

*Check the formula I've used is in cell P5.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter DATE & TIME value in required range, for example I've used N2 (applied format is `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`) to demonstrate the original Date time value.
- Now enter Date & Time value, and apply the required format `ddd dd mmm yyyy-hh:mm`, check range `N5:N8`.
- Enter Hours to subtract is required cells are in `O5:O8`, the cell format is `NUMBER`.
- Now enter the formula in cell P5:

  `=N5-TIME(O5,0,0)`
- Apply the required format `ddd dd mmm yyyy-hh:mm` on Range `P5:P8`.

**N.B.**

*Cell references & Formats are editable.*

Comment: Rajesh, thank you very much for the clear and very helpful explanation and for your time!

Comment: @Allrightallrightallright ,, glad to help you,,, if U feel then you mark this as an Answer as well Up vote ,,, and keep asking ☺

Comment: Why this has been down voted,, plzz write your concern help me to fix it !!

Comment: Hi Rajesh, as a new member I cannot up vote or downvote. Anyway your answer was clear and helpful for me. I did not downvoted your answer.

Comment: @Allrightallrightallright ,, it's okay keep asking ☺